# Elixir Agent tuple return

Tags: elixir

I am working on the following tutorial

https://howistart.org/posts/elixir/1

I am working with agents and I don't understand how this line works.

```
def pop(door) do
    Agent.get_and_update(door, fn
        []      -> {:error, []}
        [h|t]   -> {{:ok, h}, t}     ## returns {:ok, h} why not {{:ok, h}, t}
    end  )
end
```

output

```
iex(5)> Portal.Door.push(:pink, 2)
:ok
iex(6)> Portal.Door.push(:pink, 3)
:ok
iex(7)> Portal.Door.push(:pink, 4)
:ok
iex(8)> Portal.Door.pop(:pink)    
{:ok, 4}
```

A simple function with a different result

```
person = fn ( first, last ) -> {{:ok, first}, last} end
```

output:

```
iex(13)> person.("John", "Doe")                                 
{{:ok, "John"}, "Doe"}
```

Why does one return the both the inner and outer tuples and the agent only returns the inner tuple.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `Agent.get_and_update(agent, fun, timeout)` documentation [here](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Agent.html#get_and_update/3):

> Gets and updates the agent state in one operation.
>
> The function fun is sent to the agent which invokes the function
>   passing the agent state. The function must return a tuple with two
>   elements, the first being the value to return (i.e. the get value) and
>   the second one is the new state.

This is because an `Agent` is just a special case of `GenServer` that must return a response and a new state. You can check the implementation of the `Agent.Server` [here](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.1.1/lib/elixir/lib/agent/server.ex#L15)